# AngularJS | Plnkr | Watch expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I am trying to run a sample code of $watch in plnkr, however, I cannot get watch expression triggered. Do I need to trigger digest cycle?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.0" data-semver="1.3.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>    
  <body ng-app="funny" ng-controller="funController">
    <input value="{{random.text}}" />
    <div>{{number}}</div>
  </body>    
</html>
<script type="text/javascript>
    var fun = angular.module("funny",[]);
    fun.controller("funController", function($scope) {
      $scope.random = { text : "les c!" };
      $scope.number = Math.random();

      $scope.$watch("random.text", function() {
        $scope.number = Math.random();
      });
    });
</script>
```

Here is a Plunker link https://plnkr.co/edit/nfkQ6p4nc6MRwThay8Hd?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

https://plnkr.co/edit/WpIS2YffE5NabayejJsZ?p=preview

You should use **ng-model**, because value - isn't angular directive. When you use ng-model, angular automatically runs `digest`.

```
<input ng-model="random.text" />
```

Btw, it's a bad practice to use scope.watch in controller. It's better to set `ng-change` on input and call controller function.

So here is a cleaner solution https://plnkr.co/edit/iVBWdYhvnfJszNIPteuh?p=preview